# My USB driver was not shown in the virtualbox (WIN10)

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-10, usb-drive

I'm using the 6.1 version of the virtualbox in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. The USB driver in question already passed through the USB device filters (in the settings), but it is not shown in win10: when I look through Device Manager on Windows 10, the USB Mass Storage Device has an error code:

"This Device cannot start. (Code 10)" which I think is the reason why my USB driver is not even showing in the first place.

I know that my computer/Windows 10 recognizes the driver since when I plug it in, it does a sound indicating it does (?)

When I tried fixing the error code, I disabled, enabled and update the driver (and restart the OS) but none of them fixed anything.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because by default we don't have user entry for Virtualbox.
We can solve this by running the command in terminal-

```
$ sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

This will definitely solve your problem.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these :

1. Install Virtualbox extension pack [from here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. Run the following command in the terminal

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG vboxusers mir
   ```

( Replace the word `mir` with your own account name - You will find it at the top left corner of your terminal )

[image: img_terminal]